# How to change the path for JHipster generated files

Tags: jhipster

I was using old version for JHipster and recently I updated to version 3.0. I am facing trouble with the generated front end code(js, html etc). In previous version it was generating these files at below location:

```
    \src\main\webapp\scripts\app\entities
```

But due to new version it is generating to:

```
     \src\main\webapp\app\entities
```

Can someone help to provide the configuration location to correct it??

Comment: There is no migration path to jhipster 3.x for a project that was generated with jhipster 2.x, if you want to use the generator on your 2.x project, you must use the 2.x generator.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not looking for migration but I am looking for jhipster file name and it's location which has above default path so that I can update it to my project specific path i.e src\main\webapp\scripts\app\entities. so that in future new js and html file will be generated to new path not in jhipster default path.

Comment: ANGULAR_DIR in generator-jhipster/generators/generator-constants.js but I don't understand how this would help you as this is a constant used at generation time not a configurable setting that you can find in your project.

Comment: I did not find above file in project.

Comment: That's normal, it is a file of the generator and this is why I told you I doubt it could be useful to you. There's no such setting in your project, if you want to change you must fork the generator.

Comment: I decided to copy paste the generated file to old existing folder. :(